# How to listen to change feed continuously RethinkDB

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rethinkdb

I am having the following problem: with `RethinkDB` using `RunChangesAsync` method runs once and when used, it starts listening to changes on a given query. When the query changes, you are given the `Cursor<Change<Class>>` , which is a delta between the initial state and the actual state.

My question is how can I make this run continuously?

If I use:

```
while(true)
{
 code....   //changes happening while program is here
....../
...RunChangesAsync();
/......processed buffered items
code   //new changes here
}
```

If there are changes happening where i pointed in the code, they would not be caught by the `RunChanges`. The only changes that would be caught would be while `RunChanges` is listening. Not before ..or after it retrieves the results.

So I tried wrapping the `RunChanges` in an `observable` but it does not listen continuously for changes as I would have expected...it just retrieves 2 null items (garbage I suppose) and ends.

**Observable**

```
public  IObservable<Cursor<Change<UserStatus?>>> GetObservable() =>
    r.Db(Constants.DB_NAME).Table(Constants.CLIENT_TABLE).RunChangesAsync<UserStatus?>(this.con,CancellationToken.None).ToObservable();
```

**Observer**

```
class PlayerSubscriber : IObserver<Cursor<Change<UserStatus?>>>
{
    public void OnCompleted() => Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    public void OnError(Exception error) => Console.WriteLine("error");
    public void OnNext(Cursor<Change<UserStatus?>> value)
    {
        foreach (var item in value.BufferedItems)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

**Program**

```
class Program
{
    public static RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.R;
    public static bool End = false;
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var address = new Address { Host = "127.0.0.1", Port = 28015 };
        var con = await r.Connection().Hostname(address.Host).Port(address.Port).ConnectAsync();
        var database = new Database(r, con);
        var obs  = database.GetObservable();
        var sub  = new PlayerSubscriber();
        var disp = obs.Subscribe(sub);

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

When I am debugging as you can see, the `OnNext` method of the `Observer` is executed only once (returns two null objects) and then it closes.

[image]

P.S: `Database` is just a wrapper around rethinkdb queries. The only method used is `GetObservable` which I posted it. The `UserStatus` is a `POCO`.

Comment: "does not listen continously for changes as i would have expected" - Your expectation is wrong. Just calling `.ToObservable()` doesn't make it poll. You have to do that.

Comment: It's not hard to make this work, but it would be great if you could make a [mcve] - something where I can paste your code and it'll compile with the minimum of work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write: You have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a change feed, you'll want to create ***one*** change feed object. For example, when you get back a `Cursor<Change<T>>` after running `.RunChangesAsync();` that is really all you need.

The `cursor` object you get back from `query.RunChangesAsync()` is your change feed object that you will use for the entire lifetime you want to receive changes.

In your example:

```
while(true)
{
 code....   //changes happening while program is here
....../
...RunChangesAsync();
/......processed buffered items
code   //new changes here
}
```

Having `.RunChangesAsync();` in a `while` loop is not the correct approach. You don't need to re-run the query again and get another `Cursor<Change<T>>`. I'll explain how this works at the end of this post.

Also, do not use `cursor.BufferedItems` on the `cursor` object. The `cursor.BufferedItems` property on the cursor is not meant to consumed by your code directly; the `cursor.BufferedItems` property is only exposed for those special situations where you want to "peek ahead" inside the cursor object (client-side) for items that are ready to be consumed that are specific to your change feed query.

The proper way to consume items in your change feed is to enumerate over the `cursor` object itself as shown below:

```
var cursor = await query.RunChangesAsync(conn);
foreach (var item in cursor){
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

When the `cursor` runs out of items, it will make a request to the **RethinkDB** server for more items. Keep in mind, each iteration of the `foreach` loop *can be potentially a* blocking call. For example, the `foreach` loop can block indefinitely when **1)** there are no items on the client-side to be consumed (`.BufferedItems.Count == 0`) and **2)** there are no items that have been changed on the server-side according to your change feed query criteria. under these circumstances, the `foreach` loop will block until **RethinkDB** server sends you an item that is ready to be consumed.

[Documentation about using Reactive Extensions and RethinkDB in C#](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver/wiki/Extra-C%23-Driver-Features#reactive-extensions-rx-support)

There is a driver unit test that shows how .NET Reactive Extensions can work [here](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver/blob/master/Source/RethinkDb.Driver.Tests/ReQL/RxReactiveExtensionTests.cs).

Specifically, [Lines 31 - 47 in this unit test](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver/blob/master/Source/RethinkDb.Driver.Tests/ReQL/RxReactiveExtensionTests.cs#L31-L47) set up a change feed with Reactive Extensions:

```
var changes = R.Db(DbName).Table(TableName)
    //.changes()[new {include_states = true, include_initial = true}]
    .Changes()
    .RunChanges<JObject>(conn);

changes.IsFeed.Should().BeTrue();

var observable = changes.ToObservable();

//use a new thread if you want to continue,
//otherwise, subscription will block.
observable.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(
        x => OnNext(x),
        e => OnError(e),
        () => OnCompleted()
    );
```

Additionally, [here is a good example and explanation](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver/wiki/Extra-C%23-Driver-Features#consuming-changefeeds) of what happens and how to consume a change feed with C#:

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

If you have an operation that has the signature `Task<int> ReadAsync()`, then the way to set up polling, is like this:

```
IObservable<int> PollRead(TimeSpan interval)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Interval(interval)
            .SelectMany(n => Observable.FromAsync(() => ReadAsync()));
}
```

I'd also caution about you creating your own implementation of `IObservable<T>` - it's fraught with danger. You should use `Observer.Create(...)` if you are creating your own observer that you want to hand around. Generally you don't even do that.